# C++: multiple keyed map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am searching for a (multi)map where there values are associated by different key types. Basically [what was asked here for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822322/how-to-implement-a-map-with-multiple-keys) but for C++. Is there something like this already or do I have to implement it myself?

---

Another, more simple case (the above case would solve this already but there may be a more simple solution esp for this case):

I want a multimap where my values are all unique and ordered (the keys are also ordered of course) and I want to be able to do a search in the map for a specific value in O(log n) time. So I can get the associated key to a value in O(log n) time. And I can get the associated value to a key also in O(log n) time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to search both by key and by value use [boost.bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).

If you need multiple keys use [boost.multi-index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

[Boost Multi-Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: Exactly, thanks! Do you know if this is going to get into C++0x? Or sth similar?

Comment: Thought several of boost libraries are included in upcoming C++0x (in TR1 and TR2), but Multi-Index is not among them.

Comment: @Albert I doubt it, but since it'S a header-only library it's easy to use anyway.