# Can I customize the index of a matrix in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, matrix, arraylist

I want to implement in Java a matrix with custom index like this example:

```
         country1 city1 name1 region1 population1
country2    23      5    55    ...
city2       5       9    .
name2                    .
region2                  .
population2
```

That is `mat[country1][country2]` should return 23.
I don't know how I will do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely to have to use Hashmap or HashTable with a key acting like pair to contain the two indexes: `Map<Pair<K1,K2>, V>`

You can take a look at that for more informations:
[Map with two-dimensional key in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373443/map-with-two-dimensional-key-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

If you have two-dimensional tables whose rows and columns always follow this order, then you could use an enumeration of rows/columns.

For example:

```
   public static final int COUNTRY = 0;
   public static final int CITY  = 1;
   public static final int NAME = 2;
   public static final int REGION = 3;
   public static final int POPULATION = 4;
```

On the other hand, if you can have multiple countries in the data structure, in both dimensions, then you could use a Map.