# A map with two keys

Tags: java, string, dictionary, key, concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement a Map with multiple keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822322/how-to-implement-a-map-with-multiple-keys)
>   [Multiple Keys to Single Value Map Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768963/multiple-keys-to-single-value-map-java)

I have to get the value of an enum based on two incoming string attributes. I have been doing this as map for single values. Now I am faced with making a concatenation. Is there a way to have a map have two keys such that I could

```
Map.get("attr1","attr2");
```

and this would return the correct enum. Or will I simply have to concatenate all possible values and use this as the key?

I'm searching for the squeaky clean solution (aren't we all :P)

Comment: check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822322/how-to-implement-a-map-with-multiple-keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could use `Map<String, Map<String, YourEnum>>`.

We use this a lot and thus made our own `Map` implementation that provides two keys and internally uses the map-of-maps approach.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a map of maps, i.e.

```
Map.get("attr1").get("attr2");
```

or you could define a object with an equals method, i.e.

```
Map.get(new MyObject("attr1", "attr2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would make a wrapper class with those two attributes, implement `equals()` and maybe implement `Comparable` and `compareTo` delegating onto the two elements of the composite key. And use this class as key to the map.

It would be like rolling your own `Pair` class. Take a look at this question's answers, that elaborate on the matter: [What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an class that contains the two keys and use that as the map key?

For example:

```
public class BiKey implements comparable<BiKey>
{
  private String key1;
  private String key2;

  // getters and setters

  // equals and hash code.

  // implement comparable.
}

Map <BiKey, Blammy> blammyMap; // Blammy is the value type.
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Thomas's approach, we (At my work) have 'Dimensional' map classes that are simple wrappers around several Maps.

```
public class MultiKeyMap {
  private HashMap<keyOne, Object> keyOneToObjectMap;
  private HashMap<keyTwo, Object> keyTwoToObjectMap;
  ...etc


}
```

It is very easy to keep all the maps in sync with each other and allows for a decently quick search without tons of potentially complex code.  (However, this comes at the cost of increased Memory use)

Answer (score 0):

**org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiKeyMap is what you want**

http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html

example

```
 private MultiKeyMap cache = MultiKeyMap.decorate(new LRUMap(50));

 public String getAirlineName(String code, String locale) {
   String name = (String) cache.get(code, locale);
   if (name == null) {
     name = getAirlineNameFromDB(code, locale);
     cache.put(code, locale, name);
   }
   return name;
 }
```