# Retriving map-like key-key-value from POST request

Tags: servlets, post, dictionary, http-request-parameters

I've been used to do this in PHP where I can do like this in HTML:

```
<input name="a[b][c]" value="abc">
<input name="a[b][d]" value="def">
<input name="a[d][y]" value="nope">
```

Then get it in PHP e.g. as:

```
foreach($_POST['a']['b'] as $thisId => $value){
    echo "key: $thisId, value: $value\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
key: c, value: abc
key: d, value: def
```

I've tried to find but I can't seem to be able to find an equivalent in servlets.
How can I get the equivalent with plain servlets (without me doing the code itself)?
If it doesn't exist, is there a library that does that job?

**Edit:** To add up to what sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ mentions, I do not want the list of everything that I get in the request... I added another element in the example above to try to make it more clear.

Comment: I didn't know exactly. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677993/how-to-create-a-hashmap-with-two-keys-key-pair-value.

Comment: @Satya Nice try but no. I'd have to put the values there so I'd have to do the work regardless...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this ?

```
    Map<String, String[]> paramValMap = req.getParameterMap();
  for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> param : paramValMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = (String) param.getKey();
    String[] values = (String[]) param.getValue();
    out.print(key);
    for (String val : values) {
            out.println(val);
    }
  }
```

That map contains, each parameter and an array of it's values.

Comment: No. That gives me all the parameters sent through POST but there's no tree-like organization with them. Besides, if there an input with name="a[c][y]", I'd be screwed with the code above.

Comment: Still the same kind of thing. It is a more useful API but it is still the single key-value instead of key-key-key-value

Comment: Thanks for trying... it is actually still key-value... It's just that in PHP it's all hashmaps.