# How to write/put to a HashMap with two keys (Key-Pair, Value)?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I am using the first solution in this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677993/how-to-create-a-hashmap-with-two-keys-key-pair-value) to create and read a hashMap with 2 keys and one value .i.e

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, V>> map = //...

map.get(2).get(5);
```

How do I put the key/value pairs on this HashMap?

In short, I am looking to do the equivalent of

```
myMap.put(key, value);
```

but for a multi key hashmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Java 8+, you can do (if your `V` type parameter is a string):

```
map.computeIfAbsent(2, e -> new HashMap<>()).put(5, "value");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map.put(2, new HashMap<Integer, V>);

map.get(2).put(5, "value");
```