# Marker sometimes change colour on click and sometimes it does not

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have this application where I show markers on google maps for pharmacies nearby. When I click on marker I want the marker to change the colour. When I click on some other marker, it should change the previous marker's colour to default and will change new marker's colour.
This is working randomly, I mean sometimes marker colour is getting changed and sometimes it stays the default color.

```
Marker lastClicked;

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in user's location
    // User's location is taken from the postal code entered


    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            if(lastClicked != null){
                lastClicked.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
            }
            marker.setIcon(getMarkerIcon(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_color)));

            lastClicked=marker;
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Code for getMarkerIcon() method is:

```
public BitmapDescriptor getMarkerIcon(int color){
    float[] hsvFloat = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsvFloat);
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(hsvFloat[0]);
}
```

NOTE: I added debugger in every line to see what part of code does not run, and it is strange that when debugger come to this line

```
marker.setIcon(getMarkerIcon(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_color)));
```

it is getting compiled and yet sometimes it does not change the color of the marker.

Comment: Please add more source code: 1) with `lastClicked` declaration and changes, 2) `getMarkerIcon()` implementation.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko I edited and added code for getMarkerIcon(). And lastClicked declaration.

Comment: Seems everything in code that you added is ok. Try double check marker creation part may be several markers with same coordinates added.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Thank you so much for your suggestion, after your comment I checked my list and compared few markers and I found out that there were few markers with exactly same lat and lng, so markers were getting overlapped.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by checking my list of markers. From that I found that there were markers with exactly same lat and lng, that's why markers were overlapped, that means there were more than 1 markers on one

```
 public boolean isDuplicate(Pharmacy pharmacy){

        for(int i=0; i<pharmacyList.size(); i++){

            if(pharmacyList.get(i).getLatitude() == pharmacy.getLatitude()

                    &&pharmacyList.get(i).getLongitude() == pharmacy.getLongitude())

                return true;

        }

        return false;

    }
```

NOTE: Pharmacy is class that lat and lng properties.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this out

```
googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(new LatLng( 65.07213,-2.109375))
.title("This is my title")
.snippet("and snippet")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
```

Hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably at marker creation step several markers with same coordinates added and overlap each other. To check marker existence by coordinates you can use `O(1)` complexity (instead of `O(N)` for iterating over all markers case) approach  by using `LatLng` of `Marker` object as `HashMap/HashSet` key. For do that you need to implement approach described, for example, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14678042/6950238) answer of [Tomasz Nurkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605744/tomasz-nurkiewicz). For example, `Key` class can be like this:

```
public class LatLngKey {
    private LatLng mLatLng;

    public LatLngKey(LatLng latLng) {
        mLatLng = latLng;
    }

    public double getLattitude() {
        return mLatLng.latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return mLatLng.longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof LatLngKey)) return false;
        LatLngKey key = (LatLngKey) o;
        return mLatLng.latitude == key.getLattitude() && mLatLng.longitude == key.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // for better accuracy it is needed to convert double values into integer 
        int result = (int) mLatLng.latitude * 10_000;
        result = 31 * result + (int) mLatLng.longitude * 10_000;
        return result;
    }
}
```

and using of it like that:

```
...
mGoogleMap = googleMap;

Map<LatLngKey, Marker> markersMap = new HashMap<>();
LatLng positionNoida = new LatLng(28.57, 77.32);
Marker markerNoida = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(positionNoida)
        .title("Marker in Noida"));
LatLngKey markerKey = new LatLngKey(markerNoida.getPosition());
markersMap.put(markerKey, markerNoida);

LatLng positionNoida2 = new LatLng(28.57, 77.32);
Marker markerNoida2 = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(positionNoida2)
        .title("Marker in Noida 2"));
LatLngKey markerKey2 = new LatLngKey(markerNoida2.getPosition());

if (markersMap.containsKey(markerKey2)) {
    // marker with same coordinates exists 
    ...
} else {
    // marker with same coordinates do not exists 
    ...
}
...
```

You need to implement `PharmacyKey` class for your `Pharmacy`.