# Locate Objects in Collection with multiple keys

Tags: java

Have a class with attributes attr1, attr2, attr3 and attr4.

I am looking for a way to load a bunch of objects of that class in an array (or `ArrayList` or `Map` or whatever) and then being able to retrieve (search) these objects based on attr1 or attr2.

It looks like the way to go is `HashMap` but I will have to:

1. if I want only one `HashMap`, I will have two entries for each object, one with key attr1 and one with key attr2
2. have two `HashMap` objects, one with key attr1 and the other with key attr2 and based on what I am searching for, use the appropriate `Map`.

Is there any other elegant way of doing this? Is there a `Map` or `Collection` object that will allow me to provide multiple keys for an object?

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768963/multiple-keys-to-single-value-map-java).  Does this help you out?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each object's attr1 is never the same as some other object's attr2? If no, you'd better use two maps.

Answer (score 1):

I find the second solution with two Map objects quite elegant, each Map being a sort of index of your data. If you really want one single structure, then you can use Guava's [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html), who is mapping values to a pair of keys.