# Is there a viable generic alternative to apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils?

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons-collection

Is there a viable generic version of `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils`?  If not, why not?  It seems like an obvious need.  Or has the Java community just given up on functional coding until closures are added to Java 17?

Comment: Closures didn't make it into Java7.

Comment: @skaffman: that's why the OP said Java 17...

Comment: Well, we got lambdas but since they can't throw checked exceptions it's pretty lame. I guess the language will be crippled until they finally do something to disable checked exceptions somehow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a genericified port of a slightly out-of-date version of Commons Collections [here](http://larvalabs.com/collections/).  It's no longer maintained, however.

A better option is [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).  It has classes like `Lists`, `Sets`, `Collections2` etc that are the equivalent to Commons' `CollectionUtils`.  Guava is not a one-for-one port of Commons Collections, but it has a better designed and more consistent API. Takes a bit of adjusting to, if you're used to Commons Collections.

Comment: I'm happy with Guava, largely because it isn't a port of Commons Collections. It's much better designed.

Answer (score 13):

Looks like situation around [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) has changed. [API version 4.0](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html) is strongly typed. It is already available in Maven Central Repository.