# Can I have a double-keyed map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement a Map with multiple keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822322/how-to-implement-a-map-with-multiple-keys)

Imagine a table with columns K1, K2 and D. I may need to search data by keys K1 or K2 or both. Is there any 'standard' solution in Java for this apart from creating several maps keeping references?

Comment: "Imagine a table with columns K1, K2 and D." -- what do you mean by that? K1 - columns, K2 - rows and D is data in the intersection? Or K1 and K2 are columns and D is a row? In both cases it's not clear what should be returned "by keys K1 or K2 or both".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using guava's [Table](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html).

Sample from the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table)

```
Table<Vertex, Vertex, Double> weightedGraph = HashTable.create();
weightedGraph.put(v1, v2, 4);
weightedGraph.put(v1, v3, 20);
weightedGraph.put(v2, v3, 5);

weightedGraph.row(v1); // returns a Map mapping v2 to 4, v3 to 20
weightedGraph.column(v3); // returns a Map mapping v1 to 20, v2 to 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to search by only (k1, k2) tuples, I would suggest a `MultiKeyMap` or, more likely, a wrapper object going into a standard `Map`. But if you want to search by both, or one, or the other -- it sounds like an embedded SQL engine might be better.

**EDIT:** depending on your data size, whether you also need a (k1, k2, k3) lookup, how many structures like this you'll need (a SQL engine is relatively heavy), you might be better off with Mairbek Khadikov's answer of a Guava Table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to search data by a range of keys then you can use [navigable map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap%28K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean%29).

Look at this code:

```
NavigableMap<String, String> orig = new TreeMap();
orig.put("1", "A");
orig.add("2", "B");
orig.add("3", "C");
orig.add("4", "D");
orig.add("5", "E"); 
//this submap will now contain "C", "C"
SortedMap submap = orig.subMap("2", "4");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the Map in an object and provide some method that would search for data using both keys. After that, you could simply intersect the 2 result sets and return them. Nice and simple :) .