# Accessing Multikey Map in Struts2

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, struts2, multikey

Does Struts2 support Multikey Map?

If so, can I access it like,

```
<s:property value="multiKeuMap[#k1][#k2][#k3]">
```

Thanks

Comment: you mean apache common multimap?

Comment: Commons' MultiMap allows multiple values under the same key, which is different than a map with multiple keys.

Comment: @Raj: S2 does not support this multikeymap.

Comment: Did you checked http://stackoverflow.com/q/822322/1290442 ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys.. Struts2 has no support for Commons MultiMap. I had figured out an alternative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts OGNL supports Java collections and doesn't have support for MultiKeyMap.

Apache Struts documentation says that it supports Maps,Lists and Sets.

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.2/docs/ognl.html

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet retrieving value from multi key map using two keys. (using ognl expression).

```
    MultiKeyMap keyMap = new MultiKeyMap();//MultiKeyMap Creation
    keyMap.put("1","2","OneTwo");//storing value
    OgnlContext context = new OgnlContext();// Ognl Context
    context.put("vap", keyMap);
    Object expression = Ognl.parseExpression("vap.get(\"1\",\"2\")");// Ognl expression //to retrive value from multikeyMap
    System.out.println(Ognl.getValue(expression, context));//Printing value.
```

Can you try this expression for your requirement "multiKeuMap.get(\"k1\",\"k2\")"

In Jsp page can you try with this expression **"multiKeuMap.get('k1','k2')"**