# Best design/coding to accomplish the below requirement?

Tags: java

I am using Java 1.7. I have below map.

```
Map<String, String> keyValues = new HashMap<>();
```

But map can contain values as below.

```
keyValues.put("one", "value1");
keyValues.put("two", "value2");
```

OR

```
keyValues.put("four", "value1");
keyValues.put("two", "value2");
keyValues.put("seven", "value3");
```

OR

```
keyValues.put("one", "value1");
keyValues.put("two", "value2");
keyValues.put("three", "value3");
```

Basically the map can contain **N** values where is N is generic it can contain any number of values.

I have one more value for group of keys as below.

```
keys one, two belongs to 12345SRT
keys one, two, three, four belongs to 12345SRTSSS
keys four, two, seven belongs to 764RTYL87
```

Now map can contain any one of above key sets.

In that case based on the key set in the map it has to return corresponding value.

Ex:

```
If map contains one and two then it should return 12345SRT.
     If map contains four,two and seven then logic should return 764RTYL87.
```

What is the best place to keep above key sets and corresponding values?
Shall i consider enum?
The logic has to take map and return value.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Maybe it just me but your example makes me think about binary representation :)

Comment: Not sure I got your requirements correctly but it seems you just have to exchange key and value in your map.

Comment: Henry agreed. Not getting the use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache MultiKeyMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html)

Example

```
 MultiKeyMap multiKeyMap = new MultiKeyMap();
 multiKeyMap.put("New York","IBM","Sam");
 multiKeyMap.put("Sydney","Infosys","Honey");
 multiKeyMap.put("Prague","JP Morgan","Peter");
 multiKeyMap.put("Scotland","RBS","Deny");
 multiKeyMap.put("Paris","Nomura","Lily");
 multiKeyMap.put("Melbourne","Citi Bank","Sandy");
 multiKeyMap.put("Aukland","Bank of America","Tommy");
```

Resultant map

[image]

Similar question: [How to implement a Map with multiple keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822322/how-to-implement-a-map-with-multiple-keys)

---

**EDIT :**

You can have a custom key class which can have N number of keys.
Something like

```
Class MyKey{
  List<String> keys;
}

Map<MyKey, String> keyValues = new HashMap<>();
```

Also override appropriate methods of Map like `equals`,`hashcode`,`get` etc.

Comment: That doesn't help OP at all. Can you provide some code with it.

Comment: Karna, thanks for ur answer.But i here i have not two keys. it can contain one or two or three keys. Still can i use multikeymap?

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below :

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> keyValues = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>();
keyValues.put("12345SRT",["one","two"]);
keyValues.put("12345SRTSSS",["one", "two", "three", "four"]);
keyValues.put("764RTYL87",["four", "two", "seven"]);
```

Ex:if you have a map object with keys as "one" and "two"

```
String getKey(map){
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : keyValues.entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        ArrayList<string> value = e.getValue();
        if(value.containsAll(map.keySet())){
            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: venkat, but using this approach i cannot get key based on values right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
HashMap<Set<String>, String> multiMap = new HashMap<Set<String>, String>();
Set<String> mk1 = new HashSet<String>();
mk1.add("one");
mk1.add("two");
mk1.add("three");
multiMap.put(mk1, "derp");

Set<String> checker = new HashSet<String>();
checker.add("two");
checker.add("three");
checker.add("one");

if(multiMap.containsKey(checker))
    System.out.println(multiMap.get(checker));
```

Try running this and see if it's the behavior you're wanting.