# What's an efficient way to store data, access it with keys and iterate a subpart of it based on the values?

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, treemap, linkedhashmap

I have a collection of class storing some data on which I need to do the following:

- access the data quite frequently with some unique id
- access the data of a subpart of the collection based on the non-unique, ordered value of an attribute of the class

Can you think of any efficient way to do that in Java?

---

First, I thought of using a HashMap with ids as keys

- a HashMap is O(1) to get the data from the key;
- it can be sorted on values but it is inefficient when you want to get to a specific value (the whole collection gets iterated);

Then, I thought of using a TreeMap, with ordered values as keys

- a TreeMap allows an efficient iteration over the ordered values;
- the ordered values aren't unique so it should be a TreeMultimap;
- but getting a value from its id will be O(log(n));

Using the two structures simultaneously doesn't seem like a good solution either as they would have to be synchronized. I guess some kind of BiMultiMap sorted on its values with a way to iterate on it starting from a specific value would solve my problem but I can't find a way to do that.

---

I have tried to craft an example to illustrate my needs. This train thing is not my actual problem, I've tried to make it a little bit less abstract.

```
public static class Train implements Comparable<Train> {
    String id;
    int maxSpeed;
    String trainColor;

    public Train(String id, int d1, String d2){
        this.id = id;
        this.maxSpeed = d1;
        this.trainColor = d2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + " = (" + maxSpeed + ", " + trainColor + ")";
    }

    @Override 
    public int compareTo(Train o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.maxSpeed, o.maxSpeed);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    // Let's say I need two things:
    //   - the trains that can go higher than a certain speed
    //   - the train data of a particular train
    int start = 3;
    String seekedId = "FlyingScotman";

    Train d1 = new Train("HogwartExpress", 5, "blue");
    Train d2 = new Train("TGV", 4, "red");
    Train d3 = new Train("FlyingScotman", 3, "blue");
    Train d4 = new Train("OrientExpress", 2, "black");
    Train d5 = new Train("Trans-Siberian", 1, "grey");

    /******* HashMap implementation *******/

    Map<String, Train> hashMapData = new HashMap<String, Train>();
    hashMapData.put(d1.id, d1);
    hashMapData.put(d2.id, d2);
    hashMapData.put(d3.id, d3);
    hashMapData.put(d4.id, d4);
    hashMapData.put(d5.id, d5);
    hashMapData = MapUtil.sortByValue(hashMapData);

    // Bad: I have to iterate the whole collection to reach the subcollection
    System.out.println("\n>>>>>>> HashMap: subcollection");
    for(Map.Entry<String, Train> entry : hashMapData.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().maxSpeed < start) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }

    // Good: I get my data directly
    System.out.println("\n>>>>>>> HashMap: get");
    System.out.println(hashMapData.get(seekedId));

    /******* TreeMap implementation *******/

    TreeMap<Integer, Train> treeMapData = new TreeMap<Integer, Train>();
    treeMapData.put(d1.maxSpeed, d1);
    treeMapData.put(d2.maxSpeed, d2);
    treeMapData.put(d3.maxSpeed, d3);
    treeMapData.put(d4.maxSpeed, d4);
    treeMapData.put(d5.maxSpeed, d5);

    // Good: I can iterate a subcollection efficiently
    System.out.println(">>>>>>> TreeMap: subcollection");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Train> entry : treeMapData.tailMap(start).entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println("\n>>>>>>> TreeMap: get");
    // Bad: I have to iterate the whole collection to reach the data
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Train> entry: treeMapData.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().id.equals(seekedId)) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    // Also bad: the values used as keys might not be unique

}
```

Output

```
>>>>>>> TreeMap: subcollection
FlyingScotman = (3, blue)
TGV = (4, red)
HogwartExpress = (5, blue)

>>>>>>> TreeMap: get
FlyingScotman = (3, blue)

>>>>>>> HashMap: subcollection
FlyingScotman = (3, blue)
TGV = (4, red)
HogwartExpress = (5, blue)

>>>>>>> HashMap: get
FlyingScotman = (3, blue)
```

The `MapUtil.sortByValue` method is courtesy of Carter Page : [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java?rq=1)

Thanks in advance, please tell me if anything wasn't clear.

Comment: An (in-memory if needed) database?

Comment: I meant how to store it locally, accessing a database everytime I need something wouldn't make it faster, would it...?

Comment: You need multiple maps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822322/how-to-implement-a-map-with-multiple-keys . If you have non unique keys look at guava Multimap and TreeMultimap. But as suggested ealier a mem db is very convenient and pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can make wrapper-class for `HashMap` implementing `Map` and add a sorted set to store values. Guava `TreeMultiset` should be good as it allows elements with same order.

It will look like index in database. You will get faster read operations at the cost of slower modifications.

```
public class MyMap<K, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Map<K, V> {
  private HashMap<K, V> hashMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
  private TreeMultiset<V> treeMultiset = TreeMultiset.create();

  // delegate all Map methods to hashMap
  // delegate subset methods to treeMultiset
  // all mutators should make corresponding modifications to treeMultiset
}
```