# How to give Integer values in HashMap?

Tags: java, integer-hashing

In hashmap how to give Integers in below form repersentation.i tried but i can't get solution.

(1,2)=17;

Comment: You should post the code you've tried.

Comment: What type is (1,2)?? And please post what you have tried here

Comment: @kkaosninja: In directed acyclic graph edge cost to be mention in form of 1,2 = 17,   1,3 =4 like that to give

Comment: @user306128 Please add additional information and clarification directly to your question by editing it, rather than leaving comments on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a multi-key hashmap. The basic idea is to create two hashmaps and chain them together. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822322/how-to-implement-a-map-with-multiple-keys) question for a duplicate answer.

Comment: How do you know the OP wants two keys to map to 17 as opposed to a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) containing `1,2`?

Comment: I didn't really think about the tuple, good point. But then it can just be treated as an atomic, immutable key, and go about it the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a custom Tuple class. Use the code from accepted answer to this question => [Using Pairs or 2-tuples in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670982/using-pairs-or-2-tuples-in-java).

Thanks to @azurefrog for the tip.

Step 2: The type of the HashMap holding this would be

```
HashMap<Tuple, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Tuple, Integer>();
```

Hope this helps :-)