# Algorithm speed for an simple exercice

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, arraylist

=> Go to see Edit2 at the end :)

I am sorry but I don't speak English very well.. :)

The problem is simple. I have a `file.txt` with 10000 points.
And I have to count the number of possible square.

For example : **[-1,-1][2,1][4,-2][1,-4] is a square**

I made an algorithm in java but there is a big problem...
To execute it, I need **15hours** !!!

I will give you my code, and if you think I can optimize it please tell me how ! :)

**Main.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import elements.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            //String nameFile = parameters[0];
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("exercice4.txt"));
            Processing processing = new Processing();
            processing.read(fileInputStream);
            processing.maxLenght();
            //processing.changeTest();
            processing.generateSquare();
            try 
            {
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("Square.txt"));
                processing.write(fileWriter);
                fileWriter.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException exception) 
            {
                System.out.println("Erreur lors de l'écriture dans le fichier");
            }
            System.out.println(processing.countSquare());
            System.out.println("Fin");
            try 
            {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException exception) 
            {
                System.out.println("Une erreur s'est produite lors de la fermeture de l'InputStream");
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException exeption)
        {
            System.out.println("Le nom de fichier placé en paramètre est incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

**Processing.java**

```
package elements;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

import elements.*;

public class Processing
{
    private ArrayList<Point> points;
    private ArrayList<Square> squares;
    private int maxY;
    private int maxX;
    private int minX;

    public Processing()
    {
        this.points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        this.squares = new ArrayList<Square>();
        this.maxX = 0;
        this.maxY = 0;
        this.minX = 0;
    }

    public void read(FileInputStream f)
    {
        int readReturn;
        int X = 0;
        int Y = 0;
        String string = "";
        try
        {
            while ((readReturn = f.read()) != -1)
            {
                if(readReturn-48 == -38)
                {
                    Y = Integer.parseInt(string);
                    Point point = new Point(X,Y);
                    if(!presentPoint(point))
                    {
                        points.add(point);
                    }
                    string = "";
                }
                else if(readReturn-48 == -16)
                {
                    X = Integer.parseInt(string);
                    string = "";
                }
                else if(readReturn-48 == -3)
                {
                    string += "-";
                }
                else
                {
                    string += Integer.toString(readReturn-48);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Probleme lors de la lecture du fichier");
        }
    }

    public void maxLenght()
    {
        Point reference = points.get(0);
        int maxX = reference.getX();
        int minX = reference.getX();
        int maxY = reference.getY();
        int minY = reference.getY();
        for(Point point : points)
        {
            if(point.getX() < minX)
            {
                minX = point.getX();
            }
            else if(point.getX() > maxX)
            {
                maxX = point.getX();
            }

            if(point.getY() < minY)
            {
                minY = point.getY();
            }
            else if(point.getY() > maxY)
            {
                maxY = point.getY();
            }
        }

        this.maxX = maxX;
        this.maxY = maxY;
        this.minX = minX;
    }

    public boolean samePoint(Point point1, Point point2)
    {
        boolean same = false;
        if(point1.getX() == point2.getX() && point1.getY() == point2.getY())
        {
            same = true;
        }
        return same;
    }

    public boolean presentPoint(Point newPoint)
    {
        boolean present = false;
        int counter = 0;
        Point point;
        while(present == false && counter < points.size())
        {
            point = this.points.get(counter);
            if(samePoint(point, newPoint))
            {
                present = true;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return present;
    }

    public boolean presentPoint(Point botomRight, Point topLeft, Point topRight)
    {
        boolean present = false;
        boolean botomRightPresent = false;
        boolean topLeftPresent = false;
        boolean topRightPresent = false;
        int counter = 0;
        Point point;
        while(present == false && counter < points.size())
        {
            point = this.points.get(counter);
            if(samePoint(point, botomRight))
            {
                botomRightPresent = true;
            }
            if(samePoint(point, topLeft))
            {
                topLeftPresent = true;
            }
            if(samePoint(point, topRight))
            {
                topRightPresent = true;
            }
            if(botomRightPresent && topLeftPresent && topRightPresent)
            {
                present = true;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return present;
    }

    public void generateSquare()
    {
        Point testBotomRight;
        Point testTopLeft;
        Point testTopRight;
        int counter = 0;
        for(Point point : this.points)
        {
            System.out.println(counter);
            counter++;
            for(int j = 0; j < this.maxY-point.getY(); j++)
            {
                for(int i = 1; i < this.maxX-point.getX(); i++)
                {
                    if(verifiyBoundary(i, j, point))
                    {
                        testBotomRight = new Point(point.getX()+i, point.getY()+j);
                        testTopLeft = new Point(point.getX()-j, point.getY()+i);
                        testTopRight = new Point(point.getX()+i-j, point.getY()+i+j);
                        if(presentPoint(testBotomRight, testTopLeft, testTopRight))
                        {
                            Square square = new Square(point, testBotomRight, testTopLeft, testTopRight);
                            this.squares.add(square);
                            System.out.println(point.display());
                            System.out.println(testBotomRight.display());
                            System.out.println(testTopLeft.display());
                            System.out.println(testTopRight.display());
                            System.out.println("");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean verifiyBoundary(int i, int j, Point point)
    {
        boolean verify = true;
        if(point.getX() + i + j > this.maxY)
        {
            verify = false;
        }
        if(point.getX() - j < this.minX)
        {
            verify = false;
        }
        return verify;
    }

    public String countSquare()
    {
        String nbSquare = "";
        nbSquare += Integer.toString(this.squares.size());
        return nbSquare;
    }

    public void changeTest()
    {
        Point point = points.get(9);
        point.setX(0);
        point.setY(0);

        point = points.get(100);
        point.setX(0);
        point.setY(2);

        point = points.get(1000);
        point.setX(2);
        point.setY(2);

        point = points.get(1886);
        point.setX(2);
        point.setY(0);
    }

    public void write(FileWriter fileWriter)
    {
        for(Square square : squares)
        {
            try 
            {
                fileWriter.write(square.getVertexBottomLeft().display() + square.getVertexBottomRight().display() + square.getVertexTopRight().display() + square.getVertexTopLeft().display() + "\r\n");
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Erreur lors de l'écriture des carrés");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Point.java**

```
package elements;

public class Point 
{
    private int X;
    private int Y;

    public Point(int X, int Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return this.X;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return this.Y;
    }

    public void setX(int X)
    {
        this.X = X;
    }

    public void setY(int Y)
    {
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    public String display()
    {
        return ("[" + Integer.toString(this.X) + "," + Integer.toString(this.Y) + "]");
    }
}
```

**Square.java**

```
package elements;

public class Square
{
    private Point vertexBottomLeft;
    private Point vertexBottomRight;
    private Point vertexTopLeft;
    private Point vertexTopRight;

    public Square()
    {
        this.vertexBottomLeft = null;
        this.vertexBottomRight = null;
        this.vertexTopLeft = null;
        this.vertexTopRight = null;
    }

    public Square(Point vertexBottomLeft, Point vertexBottomRight, Point vertexTopLeft, Point vertexTopRight)
    {
        this.vertexBottomLeft = vertexBottomLeft;
        this.vertexBottomRight = vertexBottomRight;
        this.vertexTopLeft = vertexTopLeft;
        this.vertexTopRight = vertexTopRight;
    }

    public Point getVertexBottomLeft()
    {
        return this.vertexBottomLeft;
    }

    public Point getVertexBottomRight()
    {
        return this.vertexBottomRight;
    }

    public Point getVertexTopLeft()
    {
        return this.vertexTopLeft;
    }

    public Point getVertexTopRight()
    {
        return this.vertexTopRight;
    }
}
```

My programme stay 15h in the function **generateSquare()** in Processing.java

Thank you very much for your help !

Edit : I need to reduce the complexity = 1,000,000,000,000 how can I do that?

[image: Input View]

EDIT2 : Thanks to @BarrySW19 we reduce execution time : 5000ms now
But I need to reduce at 200-500ms, somebody have an idea?
I will give you the new code of **Processing.java**

```
package elements;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Processing
{
    private Set<Point> points;
    private List<Square> squares;
    private int maxY;
    private int maxX;
    private int minX;

    public Processing()
    {
        this.points = new HashSet<Point>();
        this.squares = new ArrayList<Square>();
        this.maxX = 0;
        this.maxY = 0;
        this.minX = 0;
    }

    /*
     * Fonction de lecture du fichier input qui stocke les points dans une structure de données adaptée
     * Ici la structure choisi de stockage de données est un hashSet.
     * param : InputStream lié au fichier dans lequel lire les données
     * 
     *  Suivant les valeur des entiers retournés on détecte un retour chariot (sauvegarde du point)
     *  ou un espace (saisie terminée de l'abscisse)
     */
    public void read(FileInputStream f)
    {
        int readReturn;
        int X = 0;
        int Y = 0;
        String string = "";
        try
        {
            while ((readReturn = f.read()) != -1)
            {
                if(readReturn-48 == -38)
                {
                    Y = Integer.parseInt(string);
                    Point point = new Point(X,Y);
                    if(!presentPoint(point))
                    {
                        points.add(point);
                    }
                    string = "";
                }
                else if(readReturn-48 == -16)
                {
                    X = Integer.parseInt(string);
                    string = "";
                }
                else if(readReturn-48 == -3)
                {
                    string += "-";
                }
                else
                {
                    string += Integer.toString(readReturn-48);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Probleme lors de la lecture du fichier");
        }
    }

    /*
     * Fonction qui sauvegarde les abscisses et ordonnés minimum et maximum des points présents
     * Ceci servira à l'optimisation du programme
     */
    public void maxLenght()
    {
        int maxX = -10000;
        int minX = 10000;
        int maxY = -10000;
        int minY = 10000;
        for(Point point : points)
        {
            if(point.getX() < minX)
            {
                minX = point.getX();
            }
            else if(point.getX() > maxX)
            {
                maxX = point.getX();
            }

            if(point.getY() < minY)
            {
                minY = point.getY();
            }
            else if(point.getY() > maxY)
            {
                maxY = point.getY();
            }
        }

        this.maxX = maxX;
        this.maxY = maxY;
        this.minX = minX;
    }

    /*
     * A l'aide de la réécriture de la fonction hashCode() et equals() cette fonction nous renvoie si un objet est présent dans le hashSet
     */
    public boolean presentPoint(Point newPoint)
    {
        return this.points.contains(newPoint);
    }

    /*
     * A l'aide de la réécriture de la fonction hashCode() et equals() cette fonction nous renvoie si un objet est présent dans le hashSet
     */
    public boolean presentPoint(Point botomRight, Point topLeft, Point topRight)
    {
        return (this.points.contains(botomRight) && this.points.contains(topRight) && this.points.contains(topLeft));
    }

    public void generateSquare() 
    {
        for(Point p: points) 
        {
            // Trouve tous les points pouvant servir de coin topRight
            Set<Point> pointsUpAndRight = points.stream().filter(p2 -> p2.getX() > p.getX() && p2.getY() >= p.getY()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            for(Point p2: pointsUpAndRight) 
            {
                // calcul les vecteurs de trasformation
                int[] transform = new int[] { p2.getX() - p.getX(), p2.getY() - p.getY() };
                if(p.getY()+transform[0] <= this.maxY && p.getX()-transform[1] >= this.minX)
                {
                    // génère les 2 points manquants
                    Point p3 = new Point(p2.getX() - transform[1], p2.getY() + transform[0]);
                    Point p4 = new Point(p3.getX() - transform[0], p3.getY() - transform[1]);
                    if(points.contains(p3) && points.contains(p4)) 
                    {
                        Square s = new Square(p, p3, p2, p4);
                        squares.add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Fonction de basique qui répond au problème de comptage de carré
     */
    public String countSquare()
    {
        String nbSquare = "";
        nbSquare += Integer.toString(this.squares.size());
        return nbSquare;
    }

    /*
     * Cette fonctionalité suplémentaire permet de stocker dans un fichier .txt les carrés présents parmi la liste de points
     */
    public void write(FileWriter fileWriter)
    {
        for(Square square : squares)
        {
            try 
            {
                fileWriter.write(square.getVertexBottomLeft().display() + square.getVertexBottomRight().display() + square.getVertexTopRight().display() + square.getVertexTopLeft().display() + " est un carré valide " + "\r\n");
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Erreur lors de l'écriture des carrés");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about you explain (in two sentences) what your algorithm is? It's great that you shared your code, but it would speed things up

Comment: how does your input look like?

Comment: This should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Voting to close it and move there.

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you need to count the possible number of squares or 'generate' them ?

Comment: `Recursion` may be faster in this case, even though it is devil incarnate. And it would be massive headache to prevent it from blowing the stack, considering the amount of data you have to go through.

Comment: hmmm, well considering your code , the time complexity is O(n^3) == 1,000,000,000,000 iterations. so 15hrs is about right (if not more)

Comment: In two sentence :

I stock all points in ArrayList, then for each points I calculate the three other points which are necessary to do a complete square. If theses points are presents in the ArrayList it is a square.

Comment: Normaly I just need to count number of square but generate square takes no more time..

Comment: nafas how can I do to reduce that? ^^ Have you an idea?

Comment: The Law : How can I do a recursive code with this problem?

Comment: @DamienFrances the problem is you are using `bruteForce`(trying all possiblities), One way that might help you is by `Sorting` the points before hand, this way you can reduce your search space

Comment: At the very least, `presentPoint()` is needlessly slow - define `hashCode()` and `equals()` for `Point`, use `Set<Point>` for the existing points and `points.contains(myPoint)` to check existence.

Comment: @nafas I haven't understood how can I reduce :/ but I know that I reduce possibility with **verifiyBoundary()** methods and with boundary in loop **j < this.maxY-point.getY()** and **i < this.maxX-point.getX()**

Comment: @JiriTousek I don't know how use hascode() I am a beginer in java programation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29

Comment: This would probably go faster with the efficiency changes people are mentioning, and with multithreading it (why only use 1 core when you may have 8+?)

Answer (score 2):

To check a value is contained in a Set has time complexity of O(1) while checking a value that contains in an array list has time complexity of O(n).

so one way to speed things up is to use `Set` rather than `ArrayList`

To use set you need to Override `hashCode` and `equals` methods:

add the following to your `Point` class

```
class Point{
...
 int hashCode=-1;


 @Override 
 public int hashCode(){
   if(hashCode==-1){
     hashCode=Objects.hash(x,y);
   }

   return hashCode;

 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object o){
  if(o instanceOf this.getClass()){
   Point p=(Point) o;
   return p.x==x && p.y==y;
  }
  return false;

 }


}
```

in class `Processing` change:

```
private ArrayList<Point> points;
```

to:

```
private HashSet<Point> points;
```

then change your method `presentPoint` into something like:

```
public boolean presentPoint(Point p ){
 return points.contains(p);  
}


public boolean presentPoint(Point p1,Point p2,Point p3 ){
 return points.contains(p1) && points.contains(p2) && points.contains(p3);  
}
```

Comment: Now it is very fast but it non-functioning ahah
All Square are not seen now.. I just did that you said

Comment: @DamienFrances mate, I missed an `=` sign in hashCode function, i've edited it now

Comment: no problem i saw it ;)
but it is the algorithm which are false because all square are not seen..

Comment: hmm, strange, the logic is exactly as it was before. except one thing, that Set, doesn't allow duplicates, so two same points are not allowed in the set

Comment: why when I debug at the first iteration the first point is : x = -38; y = 217 whereas normaly it is : x = 123; y = -825 as you can see on the picture posted..

Comment: oh !! I maybe found.. When we use set, are item sorted?

Comment: @DamienFrances hashSet, does its own sorting evaluations, so yeah the items in set are not ordered as you expect it to be

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Changed solution to find squares rotated in any direction.

Ok, this is my stab at a solution - it should have O(N^2) performance. Firstly, I've replaced the List of points with a Set which automatically de-duplicates the set of points and also makes checking whether a point exists much faster (**you need to implement equals() and hashCode() on the Point class for this to work**).

Next, when checking for squares the first thing I do is build a Set of all points which are up and right of the current point (i.e. they could form the edge 0

In pseudo-code:

```
for each Point
   for each Point up and right of this
      calculate the other two points of the square
      if those points exists
         add the square to the answers
      end-if
   end-loop
end-loop
```

My version of the Processing class (just the important method) which implements this is:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

public class Processing {
    private Set<Point> points = new HashSet<>();
    private List<Square> squares = new ArrayList<>();

    public void generateSquare() {
        for(Point p: points) {
            // Find other points which could form a left-hand edge
            Set<Point> pointsUpAndRight = points.stream()
                    .filter(p2 -> p2.getX() >= p.getX() && p2.getY() > p.getY())
                    .collect(toSet());
            for(Point p2: pointsUpAndRight) {
                int[] transform = new int[] { p2.getX() - p.getX(), p2.getY() - p.getY() };
                Point p3 = new Point(p2.getX() + transform[1], p2.getY() - transform[0]);
                Point p4 = new Point(p3.getX() - transform[0], p3.getY() - transform[1]);
                if(points.contains(p3) && points.contains(p4)) {
                    Square s = new Square(p, p3, p2, p4);
                    squares.add(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but there is an error :/
What is groupingBy? Eclipse said that method is undefined

Comment: Imagine there is a problem because he tells me that there are 0 squares finally.. :/

Comment: groupingBy should be statically imported as "import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy". "pointsAbove" will be a set of all points vertically above the current point on the Y-axis.

Comment: I understood your code !! ahah
But there is a problem :/ I will explain you and maybe you'll can resolve it :)
I think code is good for square which have example point (0,0) (0,2) (2,0), (2,2)
But square which have : (-1,-1) (2,1) (4,-2) (1,-4) is not seen by your algo.. Do you understand? My english is very bad ^^

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise it had to find squares rotated like that... hmm, will try and think of the best solution.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You will save me ahah

Comment: have you an idea so? Because for keep a good complexity I don't see how can I do :)

Comment: Well, I've edited the solution - I think it should find all squares now, but it has O(N^2) performance. It processes 10,000 points in about 9sec on my old iCore3. I think there might be a faster way involving sorting the points first though.

Comment: Thank you very much ! People ask me to do this between 200ms and 500ms do you think it is possible? To do this I think I need to reduce complexity but I think if it was possible you should find it no?

Comment: Maybe there is some clever maths to make it faster, but I don't know it. I can get it down to about 3.5sec by running it in parallel over 4 cores, but that's still slower than you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Damien, the problem is that you spend a lot of time iterating through the List.
Try to introduce data structure with quicker search, for example, Map with two keys.

If you have structure like

```
SpacialMap<Integer, Integer, Point>
```

you can perform fast Point existence check by its coordinates, so the computational complexity will drop to O(n^2) at least.

Look at this thread to get a hint, how to implement multikey maps: [How to implement a Map with multiple keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822322/how-to-implement-a-map-with-multiple-keys)

EDIT: To improve further, the resulting algorithm can look like this:

1. Pick next point *p* from the list
2. For every point *p1* such that `p.y == p1.y && p.x < p1.x` check if there are two more points present to complete the square (note that if you array is not sorted initially there could be two possible squares for each two points on the same ordinate)
3. If so, add 1 (or 2) to the squares counter.

Comment: Thank you very much I will study this for the moment :)

If somebody have an other idea don't hesitate and tell me :)

Comment: Can you share a few lines of input please? (pouvez-vous quelques lignes de input  sil vous plait)

Comment: @ngund To do this I need to make two maps but I can't have co-ordinates with two maps.. It is not possible or I don't see how can I use it..

Comment: @PankajVaidya I screened my input on the question :)

Comment: Let me put it another way,
what is ur input form?

1) 4 points per line?
2) All points on the same line? If yes, then do we count nested squares?

Comment: You don't need a multi-key map - Point can be the key of a Map provided the equals() and hashCode() methods are correctly implemented.