# Hash map with multiple keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

Can I have a hash map in Java that looks like this?

```
HashMap<String, String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, String, Integer>()
```

My question is similar to this one here[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822322/how-to-implement-a-map-with-multiple-keys)

I'm a newbie to Java. So what I want to know is, what would be the best data structure to use if I need something like above, if that is not valid?

Comment: No, but you can have `HashMap<Pair<String, String>, Integer> hmap`.

Comment: @rowana you can create a new class holding two `String` objects and use it as a key.

Answer (score 2):

Create a simple class holding two `String` objects:

```
public class MyKey {
    private String a;
    private String b;

    // ... accessors, mutators etc.
}
```

And then use it's objects as keys in your map:

```
HashMap<MyKey, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<>()
```

Later, to add a new entry:

```
hmap.put(new MyKey("a", "b"), 2);
```

Comment: I need to search for one of the strings, if there is a pattern match, extract the other. How could I do that here?

Comment: @rowana I think that's not in the scope of your original question, please post a new one. But I'd probably try to iterate through map's entry set, check key part and then extract the other in the same loop.

Comment: @Jezor but this time using map structure wont be meaningful. He can just use a list.